# the_post() is printing titles in page footer

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, shortcode

I'm making a really simple cycle where I need to print a Custom Post Type with my style (that isn't defined yet in the script below but is where I print the_thime) and it's working.
The problem is that in the bottom of the page, just before the footer, "something" is printing the title of my posts.

That's the function:

```
function shortcode_eventi() {
     query_posts(array( 
                'post_type' => 'eventi'
    ) );  
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></small>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<p class="center"><?php _e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here."); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php   
}
```

No ideas about the problem.

Comment: if you remove "the_content()", then that title will disappear?

Comment: @Deepakjha it seems that the while turns in an infinite loop because the page netver stops to load

Comment: instead of "query_posts", use WP_Query
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Yes, using WP_Query I've not this kind of problem, thanks @Deepakjha

Comment: so your problem got resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `query_posts()`, use `WP_Query()`:

```
function shortcode_eventi() {
     $loop = new WP_Query(array( 
         'post_type' => 'eventi'
     ));  
?>
    <?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></small>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
        <p class="center"><?php _e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here."); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php   
}
```

[Read about WP_Query on the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

[Also read this good piece, why not to use `query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)